# xa_open failure with SQLCODE=-1032

Tags: db2

I am using a Tuxedo(v12.2.2.0.0) on Linux（x64) to access DB2 on mainframe through DB2 Connect Server(v9.7).

Now i meet a problem that the TMS_UDB can not start up。
From Tuxedo ULOG, it says:

> ERROR: tpopen TPERMERR xa_open returned XAER_RMERR

I checked db2dial log it shows:

```
2018-XX-XX-xxxx E4387E703   LEVEL: Error
PID     : 12673 TID: 139892007870912 PROC: TMS_UDB
INSTANCE: db2inst1
HOSTNAME: XXXX
FUNCTOIN: DB2 UDB, XA DTP Support, sqlxaConnect, probe: 5329
MESSAGE : XA Interface SQLCA
DATA #1 : SQLCA, PD_DB2TYPE_SQLCA, 136 bytes
 sqlcaid : SQLCA   sqlcabc: 136 sqlcode: -1032 sqlerrml:0
 sqlerrmc:
 sqlerrp : SQLJCMN
 sqlerrd : (1) 0x81360012 (2) 0x00000012 (3) 0x00000000
           (4) 0x00000002 (5) 0x00000004 (6) 0x00000000
 sqlwarn : (1)   (2)   (3)   (4)   (5)   (6)
           (7)   (8)   (9)   (10)  (11)
 sqlstate: 00000
```

Any DB2 export, how can i make it fixed ? thanks

I have verified DB2 client CONNECT command($ db2 connect to DBXX user USERxx using PASSXX), and query out data using SELECT statement.
and also have following the Tuxedo guide to set DB2 configuration items.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26665_01/artrt/docs11gr1/cicsref/db2conn.html

Comment: The most likely reason for the -1032 sqlcode is that at least one required Db2-instance is not running at the time the XA_OPEN is called. If the Db2-instance(s) are local (on Linux) , verify the db2sysc process is running and active for each required instance, and verify connectivity to databases for the user-account that Tuxedo uses to connect.  Also you should always give your Db2-version/fixpack when asking for help, and your Linux platform (x64, power, Z etc).

Comment: Thank you @mao; i am using a DB2 Connect Server to access DB2 on mainframe. Tuxdeo and DB2 Connect Server are both installed on Linux x64; DB2 Connect Server version is 9.7; and it's fine to connect to DB2 mainframe using db2 command "connect to DS user USER using PASSWD", data on table can be retrieved also.

Comment: So your question is misleading, you are not really connecting to UDB, it's simply a gateway.  Edit your question to add the new facts.  Has the connection from Tuxedo with XA ever worked on this node? Or is it a new installation?  If it worked previously, determine what changed and do eliminations to find out which change broke it. If it's a new setup, ensure both Tuxedo and Db2-connect are correctly configured for XA as per the documentation for both products. See also https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.dbconn.doc/doc/t0006168.html

Comment: Thanks, i will try; it's new installed, never succeed.

Comment: another information. If I use "DB2 Advanced Enterprise Server Edition", xa_open is OK, and if use "DB2 Connect Server" xa_open will fail,  there is no any changed on both Tuxedo and DB2 mainframe side. There must be something special on "DB2 Connect Server".

Comment: @mao issue resolved; stupid operate,
After set following items (as https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26665_01/artrt/docs11gr1/cicsref/db2conn.html):
db2 update dbm cfg using tp_mon_name TUXEDO
db2 update dbm cfg using spm_name bjaix
db2 update dbm cfg using max_connections 500
db2 update dbm cfg using max_coordagents 200

db2 instance should be restarted, db2stop && db2start; then thing is going well.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Converting the comment thread to an answer.

For a new installation of Tuxedo where XA transactions are required (managed by Tuxedo as TP monitor) with one leg being Db2 for Z/OS, it is necessary to configure both Tuxedo and Db2-connect to support XA transactions, in addition to basic actions for Db2 connectivity and in addition to any Db2 licensing activities.

Note that Linux/AIX/Windows: command-line connections (from the workstation to Db2 for Z via Db2-connect) will only verify connectivity and userid/password access, but this will not test XA. Command-line connections are Type-1 connections (i.e they are not using distributed units of work).

The configuration details can be version specific so always consult the version-specific documentation for both Tuxedo and Db2-connect products.

For Tuxedo, the documentation page is 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26665_01/artrt/docs11gr1/cicsref/db2conn.html

For Db2-Connect v9.7 (later versions are also accessible from here) the page is:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.dbconn.doc/doc/t0006168.html

Typical configuration for Db2-connect includes:

```
`db2 update dbm cfg using tp_mon_name TUXEDO 

db2 update dbm cfg using spm_name bjaix  # hostname of the node running Db2-connect

db2 update dbm cfg using max_connections 500 

db2 update dbm cfg using max_coordagents 200 

// You may also want to enable the Db2-connect connection-concentrator depdending on your peak concurrency needs and the available resources

db2stop

db2start`
```

Additional configuration of Tuxedo is required, in part referencing some of the Db2-configuration, refer to the Oracle Tuxedo [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26665_01/artrt/docs11gr1/cicsref/db2conn.html) for details.